# Room update query

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I'm using Room persistence library for Android and trying to make 'update' query for the boolean field.

```
@Update
suspend fun updateProduct(product: Product)
```

Product entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "products")
data class Product(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "price") val price: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "count") val count: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isPurchased") val isPurchased : Boolean = false
) {
    @PrimaryKey var id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date") var date: Long = Date().time
}
```

Similar queries as delete, insert work fine. The underhood query should find the id of product and update all fields but it doesn't work. Please don't write about insert query instead update, it's a dirty trick.

**Update:** update method returns 0 and it means it doesn't work, according to docs it should return num of updated record:

> Although usually not necessary, you can have this method return an int
>   value instead, indicating the number of rows updated in the database.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
@Query("UPDATE products SET price=:price WHERE id = :id")
void update(Float price, int id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the docs it says you have to do something like this:

```kotlin
@Update 
fun updateProduct(product: Product) // no need of suspend
```

also you can control what happen [`onConflict`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Update#onconflict). Note that if you don't specify by default it is `OnConflictStrategy.ABORT` which roll back the transaction and does nothing. So you might wanna add something like `@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's late but this solution works for me.

Make sure that `Product` object that you pass in @Update query it has same id which you have defined as primary key.